# OSPF - Lower RID elected as DR?

Tags: ospf

Two routers, ethernet link, priority both set to default of 1, R1 sits exclusively in AREA 1 with RID: 192.168.23.3.  R2 is the ABR leading to AREA 0, RID: 192.168.23.2.  No other routers in AREA 1.

Why is R2 winning the DR election?  This seems very straightforward that 192.168.23.3 RID should win for this segment.  Output of election process for perspective:

```
*Dec 29 14:57:54.291: OSPF-10 ADJ   Fa0/0: DR/BDR election
*Dec 29 14:57:54.295: OSPF-10 ADJ   Fa0/0: Elect BDR 192.168.23.3
*Dec 29 14:57:54.295: OSPF-10 ADJ   Fa0/0: Elect DR 192.168.23.2
*Dec 29 14:57:54.295: OSPF-10 ADJ   Fa0/0: Elect BDR 192.168.23.3
*Dec 29 14:57:54.299: OSPF-10 ADJ   Fa0/0: Elect DR 192.168.23.2
*Dec 29 14:57:54.299: OSPF-10 ADJ   Fa0/0: DR: 192.168.23.2 (Id)   BDR: 192.168.23.3 (Id)
```

Comment: Hard to say without more data (like the configs), but one explanation is that R2 comes up first.

Comment: So, I considered that R1 wasn't configured for say 40s before the adjacency formed so that by that time R2 had already elected itself for that segment, but I removed the adjacency for over a minute to force it to re-elect, maybe this wasn't an appropriate mechanism to use for re-election.  There is very little to the config beyond what I posted but I of course can provide anything you'd like to see.. I just figured that only RID would be relevant to this discussion.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

R1 does not become the DR because DR election in OSPF is not preemptive.  That means that once a router (R2 in this case) becomes the DR, it remains the DR even if a new adjacency is formed with another router with a higher RID.

In other words, a DR gets elected "President for Life."

Comment: Between yours and Rons post (specifically the point about 'unless the DR goes down', this is the cause of the problem and thus the answer to this question.  My theory of shutting down R1 to force re-election did nothing because the DR would've had to go down.  If either one of you wants to clean that up and make the cause and solution more direct I'll mark an answer.  Thank you again to both of you for helping me understand the re-election trigger and root cause of this interesting problem!

Comment: @AL Does this sound better?

Comment: Indeed sir!  This explicitly answers my question, I do however want to receive Ron's response to my last comment though before I mark as answer since he did create the first official answer in response and may have another view which we could integrate into the selected answer for more context, mainly because I think that the audience viewing this question may not necessarily be aware of the mechanic of self declaration as DR on a link with no other participants and so the above may be confusing / require qualification so that the answer has broader application.

Comment: (My thought process being: Someone could read this answer and argue this point: "But there were only two routers on this link, and this was the initial 'election', so what's to preempt, 192.168.23.3 should've been the DR out the gate" - if that makes sense)

Comment: Choose whichever answer you like, but initially there was only one router, R2, and it elected itself.  The election process doesn't require more than one router.  Networking isn't very democratic ;-p

Answer (score 1):

You really haven't provided enough information to be completely sure, but a router coming up first will decide it is the DR, and if there is already a DR, there will not be a DR election unless the DR goes down. Also, according to [RFC 2328, OSPF Version 2](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2328.txt), the BDR is elected first, which appears to be the case in what you have in your question. If Router 2 is the DR, then Router 1 is elected as the BDR.

The algorithm for DR/BDR election from Section 9.4:

> 1. Note the current values for the network's Designated Router and
>      Backup Designated Router.  This is used later for comparison
>      purposes.
> 2. Calculate the new Backup Designated Router for the network as
>      follows.  Only those routers on the list that have not declared
>      themselves to be Designated Router are eligible to become Backup
>      Designated Router.  If one or more of these routers have declared
>      themselves Backup Designated Router (i.e., they are currently
>      listing themselves as Backup Designated Router, but not as
>      Designated Router, in their Hello Packets) the one having highest
>      Router Priority is declared to be Backup Designated Router.  In case
>      of a tie, the one having the highest Router ID is chosen.  If no
>      routers have declared themselves Backup Designated Router, choose
>      the router having highest Router Priority, (again excluding those
>      routers who have declared themselves Designated Router), and again
>      use the Router ID to break ties.
> 3. Calculate the new Designated Router for the network as follows.  If
>      one or more of the routers have declared themselves Designated
>      Router (i.e., they are currently listing themselves as Designated
>      Router in their Hello Packets) the one having highest Router
>      Priority is declared to be Designated Router.  In case of a tie, the
>      one having the highest Router ID is chosen.  If no routers have
>      declared themselves Designated Router, assign the Designated Router
>      to be the same as the newly elected Backup Designated Router.
> 4. If Router X is now newly the Designated Router or newly the Backup
>      Designated Router, or is now no longer the Designated Router or no
>      longer the Backup Designated Router, repeat steps 2 and 3, and then
>      proceed to step 5.  For example, if Router X is now the Designated
>      Router, when step 2 is repeated X will no longer be eligible for
>      Backup Designated Router election.  Among other things, this will
>      ensure that no router will declare itself both Backup Designated
>      Router and Designated Router.
> 5. As a result of these calculations, the router itself may now be
>      Designated Router or Backup Designated Router.  See Sections 7.3 and
>      7.4 for the additional duties this would entail.  The router's interface state should be set accordingly.  If the router itself is
>      now Designated Router, the new interface state is DR.  If the router
>      itself is now Backup Designated Router, the new interface state is
>      Backup. Otherwise, the new interface state is DR Other.
> 6. If the attached network is an NBMA network, and the router itself
>      has just become either Designated Router or Backup Designated
>      Router, it must start sending Hello Packets to those neighbors that
>      are not eligible to become Designated Router (see Section 9.5.1). 
>      This is done by invoking the neighbor event Start for each neighbor
>      having a Router Priority of 0.
> 7. If the above calculations have caused the identity of either the
>      Designated Router or Backup Designated Router to change, the set of
>      adjacencies associated with this interface will need to be modified.
>      Some adjacencies may need to be formed, and others may need to be
>      broken.  To accomplish this, invoke the event AdjOK?  on all
>      neighbors whose state is at least 2-Way.  This will cause their
>      eligibility for adjacency to be reexamined (see Sections 10.3 and
>      10.4).

Comment: I've seen this explanation around but in reading it closely I don't agree this states the BDR is elected first because it clearly says: "Only those routers on the list that have not declared themselves to be Designated Router are eligible to become Backup Designated Router" - key point being 'that have not delcared themselves to be DR" (implying DR selection already occurred).  This phenomenon isn't directly the cause of my problem, though point 7 seems to be.  Thank you either way for your input Ron!

Comment: Step 2 is to elect the BDR, then the DR is elected in step 3. The BDR is clearly decided first. The rest of the section goes on to describe why this is so. This is the RFC for OSPFv2 that is the definitive explanation and standard. When a router has declared itself to be the DR, there was no election. An election implies that the other routers have declared it the DR. If R2 decides, on its own, that it is the DR, then it will be the DR unless it goes down, and there will be no DR election, although there will be a BDR election.

Comment: Ron, thanks for your response, it helps highlight an even more important point in that same quotation from my last response and that is: "DECLARED" *not* ELECTED.  And that is why I misinterpreted the above.  While this settles my understanding of the RFC's language, I still cannot fully understand why you believe BDR election to be the root cause of why R2 is the DR in the listed scenario - and not for instance the mechanic of declaration of self as a DR in the absence of any other participants on the link.  Could you help me to understand your point there?  Thank you!

Comment: As @RonTrunk put more eloquently, elections are not preemptive. If R2 comes up first and decides it is the DR, it will tell that to R1 in the Hellos when R1 comes up. R1 will not be considered for DR, but there is no BDR, so it gets elected BDR. One interesting note about DR/BDR elections not being preemptive, at least for Cisco, is that if you change the DR or BDR priority to `0`, then there is an election for the one that is now `0`, even if the router never goes down.

Comment: Ron(M), that's and awesome point (prio set to 0 to force re-election) because that seems a much stronger alternative to shutting the adj down to force it (which is what I had to do in the lab).  It seems then that Cisco's implementation of OSPF triggers the 'AdjOK' event if either the DR's int is shutdown or the priority is set to 0.  So interesting, and thank you again.  At this point I motion to include the stipulations of self declaration and how to force re-election into Ron (T)'s answer so that we have something comprehensive for people in the future.  What do you think?

Comment: That's fine, but it is up to @RonTrunk to change his answer. I'm not comfortable doing that for him.

Answer (score 1):

**CREDIT:** 
Ron Trunk and Ron Maupin generated all of the answer content, I simply produced this post for organizational purposes / clarity for future readers.

**ROOT CAUSE:**
R2 via some mechanism was already considered a DR for the link R1/R2 shared and so, regardless of it having a lower RID, it maintained it's position as the DR for that link since DR status is non-preemptive in OSPF.

**ADDITIONAL CONTEXT:**
If there is only one router on a link which would generally elect a DR/BDR, that router may DECLARE itself the DR.  Re-election of the DR status will only happen upon the trigger of the AdjOK? event.  It appears that in the Cisco implementation of OSPF this can be generated in two ways:

1. Shutting down the DR interface (disruptive)
2. Setting the DR interfaces priority to 0 (non-disruptive)

Comment: Ron/Ron - Do you both agree to the accuracy of the above?  If so, I will mark as answer.  Thank you again for all of your discussion / input!

Comment: You make it sound like there's some mysterious process that makes R2 initially the DR.  The election process is the same whether there is one router or one hundred. R2 performed the election when there were no other routers on the link.  So it determined that itself was the DR.

Comment: Also, in your "Additional Context," It's not "may declare," it's "will declare" on any broadcast network, since it runs the election algorithm first.

Comment: Ron, thank you!  I'll make all the edits at once regarding may/will.  For the point about election vs declaration.  How does the election occur if you said the BDR is elected first, but in the BDR election dialogue it states only if it's not already declared itself (not elected) a DR. If election took place wouldn't it then be more accurate to say: "The BDR is elected first, unless there is only one router in the election, in which case the DR is elected first"?